# Makefile with two C++ files : How can I choose the file to compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

Let's say I have two C++ main files, `project.cpp`, and `projectgraph.cpp`. 
They both use the same header file `functions.h`, as well as the file `functions.cpp`.

To compile `project.cpp`, I'm using the following makefile :

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -w -Wall -g 

project: project.o functions.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o project projet.o functions.o 

functions.o: functions.h

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

I would like to be able to choose between `project.cpp` and `projectgraph.cpp` to be compiled using the `make` command in the terminal. For example :

- If I type `make` in the terminal : `project.cpp` would be compiled.
- If I type `make graph` in the terminal : `projectgraph.cpp` would be compiled.

How can I change the makefile to get this result ?

Thanks !

Comment: Just add the single line: `graph: projectgraph.o functions.o`  Let the implicit rules work for you.  Add the line after your `project` rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a target for the additional program. Also, `functions.cpp` needs to be in the dependency list for `functions.o`, and `functions.h` should be in the dependency list of `project` and `projectgraph`.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -w -Wall -g 

project: project.o functions.o functions.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o project projet.o functions.o 

functions.o: functions.cpp functions.h

projectgraph: projectgraph.o functions.o functions.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o project projet.o functions.o 

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

Then you can use

```
make projectgraph
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is :

```
graph : project.o functions.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o projectgraph projectgraph.o functions.o
```

At least,  that is what I have done int he past.    There is a whole lot more you can do to make project the default etc but the above should be what you asked for.